# how to create new Asp.Net_SessionId in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to create new Asp.Net_SessionId whenever user LoggedIn to my system. How can i create it and if i cannot create it then what may be the approach to update Asp.Net_SessionId value,  I means should i save Guid.NewGuid() in Asp.Net_SessionId to create a new value of Asp.Net_SessionId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the session ID, you have to create a custom session provider, not an easy task and not something I'd recommend getting into.  Why create the user a session ID?  If you want to give them a unique ID, then create your own guid identifier and store it in session, and refer to this for your own personal needs...

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

You want to implement your own [ISessionIDManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.isessionidmanager.aspx) which "creates and validates session-identifier values, and manages the storage of a session identifier in the HTTP response as well as the retrieval of a session-identifier value from the HTTP request."

This is not the same as a [SessionStateStoreProviderBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase.aspx) which is the actual implementation for a data store.